# Pewdiepie's tuber simulator network under maintenance

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

From yesterday my network got under maintenance and I can't contribute to.

At first I thought it was under maintenance but actually 2 members of my network can contribute so I think something is wrong with me.

[image: Pewdiepie's tuber simulator Screenshot 1]

[image: Pewdiepie's tuber simulator Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your app, I had the same problem and it worked.